# How to check a specific value for a key in python

Tags: python

I am developing a basic registration and login code for a school project. I have created a dict which has some keys and values as usernames and passwords but when entering a password of a different username to another username, the code validates and continues. I want the code to check the value for the specific username and validate it.

I am just a beginner and this just a rough code of my project.

```
fa='Y'
while fa=='y' or fa=='Y':
    user_name=input("Enter Username : ")
    password=input("Enter Password : ")
    if user_name in up.keys():
        if password in up.values():
            print("Valid Username and Password.Login Completed")
        else:
            print("Invalid Password for the Usename. Login Failed")
    else:
        print('Invalid Username. Register to Login ')
    fa=input("Login Again (Y) :")
print(up)
```

Comment: `if user_name in up: ... if up[user_name] == password: ...`.

Comment: you can use `up.get(username) == password`

Comment: You do not want to test whether the password is in `up.values()`. You want to test whether it is `up[user_name]`. Just change you test accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
if user_name in up.keys():
        if password in up.values():
```

It means that you check that the username already exists and so for the password. For example, if the user enter his/her username and the password fo another username, your code will consider that login completed.

You have to check if the entered password corresponds to the username by doing:

```
     if user_name in up.keys():
           if password == up[username]:
```

Another thing, you have to stop you while loop when login is completed:

```
loggedin = False
while (fa=='y' or fa=='Y') and not loggedin:
...
...
     if user_name in up.keys():
           if password == up[username]:
                 loggedin = True
                 print("Valid Username and Password.Login Completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below.  Your mistake is that you're checking all passwords
Not the value stored for your user.

```
fa='Y'
while fa=='y' or fa=='Y':
    user_name=input("Enter Username : ")
    password=input("Enter Password : ")
    if user_name in up.keys():
        # The pass needs to match the value stored in user.  Not in all available values.
        if password == up[user_name]:
            print("Valid Username and Password.Login Completed")
        else:
            print("Invalid Password for the Usename. Login Failed")
    else:
        print('Invalid Username. Register to Login ')
    fa=input("Login Again (Y) :")
print(up)
```

To summarise, `up[user_name]` will return the value of that username from the dict.

Hope that helps you further?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {...}
check = X

for key, value in d.items():
    if value == check:
        return (key, value)
```

or just:

```
if x in d.vlaues():
    ...
```

if you only need to validtae.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check that the provided password matches that stored in the `username => password` entry in the dictionary.

So instead of

`if password in up.values()`

which checks the entire dictionary for the password.

instead try

`if up[user_name] == password`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if user_name in up:
    if password == up[user_name]:
       ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the user_name with the key and the password with the value ie. up[key]. The found variable determines whether the user_name is present inside the dictionary up or not. Here I have coded the entire thing you can refer it.

```
up = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
fa='Y'
while fa=='y' or fa=='Y':
    user_name=input("Enter Username : ")
    password=input("Enter Password : ")
    found = 0
    for key in up:
        if key == user_name:
            found = 1
            if up[key] == password:
                print("Valid Username and Password. Login Completed")
                break
            else:
                 print("Invalid Password for the Usename. Login Failed")
                 break
    if found == 0:
        print("Invalid Username. Register to Login")
    fa=input("Login Again (Y) :")
print(up)
```